# Sorting in Underscore js

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

I am working on a function that will sort my list under midterm score grade ascendingly. So I tried the ff codes:

```
if(score === 'Midterm Score'){
         _.each(students, function(elem, index, list){
           _.sortBy(students, function(elem){
              console.log(elem.midterm_score);
           });
          });
       }
```

So using the `elem.midterm_score` it did not sort my list via midterm score as can be seen here.

[image]

I expect it to be 90, 80, 70 and so on something like that. Any idea what am I missing? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the sortBy method in the wrong way. Check it in the [docs](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy)

```
// First of all we need students
var students = [
    {name: 'a', midterm_score: 60}, 
    {name: 'b', midterm_score: 70}, 
    {name: 'c', midterm_score: 40}
];

// Sort by midterm score and assign to students variable
students = _.sortBy(students, 'midterm_score');

// print array in each loop
_.each(students, function(el) {
    console.log(el);
});
```

Comment: Yeah I think this one works. I should have switch the places of the each and just put the sorted items in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy):

> Returns a (stably) sorted copy of list, ranked in ascending order by
>   the results of running each value through iteratee. iteratee may also
>   be the string name of the property to sort by (eg. length).

It may be that you are overcomplicating things. To sort the list based on the value of a property such as `midterm_score`, simply pass it as the second argument, as such:

`sortBy(students, 'midterm_score');`

Using a function as the `iteree` is for transformations on your data, which does not seem necessary here. You are expected in such a function to return the transformed result, using the `return` command explicitly (according to the docs).